# MySql - Inserting multiple rows with a joined subquery?

Tags: sql, mysql, join, subquery

This query will return a list of project IDs that represent forum threads:

```
SELECT id FROM `proj_objects` WHERE  type='fthread';
```

This query will subscribe a user (whose ID in the users table is '37') to the forum thread with an ID of '122':

```
INSERT INTO `subscrips` VALUES ( 37, 122 ) ;
```

I'd like to insert multiple rows that will subscribe user 37 to all project objects where type is fthread. Can I do this in a single query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO `subscrips` 
SELECT 37, id 
  FROM `proj_objects` 
 WHERE type = 'fthread'
```

Comment: Thanks, worked Great for a query which was returning some ids, and I wanted to insert some rows in another table based on the former ids.